# Root partition is getting full

Tags: partitioning, root

I am new ubuntu user. I have installed ubuntu few days ago and its root partition is getting full every moment. Why can this happen?

Comment: you made it too small. If there isn't anything important, I'd reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: How big is your partition ?

Comment: when i installed for the first time, i gave 25gb. It got full. I reinstalled it with 70gb. Now 22gb is full (Yesterday was 15gb) and is filling up every second

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem normal, you might have a process writing a lot of logs or something like that. What is the output of `sudo du -sh /*`command ? (it may take some time, but it will help you to localise where all these data are)

Comment: What brand/model system? Some need boot parameter to prevent runaway log files. Asus x555u w/o pci=nomsi - space issue on drive and runaway log files filling drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2327103&page=3

Comment: in 20 minutes it increases 2G (i did sudo du -sh /var/log)

Comment: it is asus a541u

Comment: i removed some log files(old ones and copies) now 18% is used

Answer (score 0):

One of the cause of this is a log file going crazy and being filled up with, the du -sh is ok but your going to be hunting around your system.

I would start at /var/logs and run watch on it, see if how much it grows over an hour or 3.

`sudo watch du -sh /var/log`

You can try other directories like /home as well.

Comment: in 20 minutes it increases 2G

Comment: I know this was a few days ago, but did you find the cause?

Comment: Yeah, log files were filling up root